# Create an Alert on Windows Dekstop via PHP?

Tags: php, eventtrigger

I've been searching on the internet and have come back with nothing, so I'm asking for no one to do this for me, only asking two simple things.

is it possible to create a desktop alert by running a PHP Script through Windows Task Scheduler, capturing the output and displaying a desktop notice? All this through PHP; Or would I have to go to another programming language such as C?

I'm aware that it's possible to use a Linux Cronjob to run a PHP Script at a set interval, capture the output with `exec();` and use `mailto();` to send an E-mail notification on finding the `needle in the haystack` but I want something like this on a windows solution, but my researching/knowledge into this has come up with no results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is *possible*, however it will probably be difficult and I don't know the specifics. Writing anything other than a web app in php is extremely uncommon, so there's very little know-how and few bindings out there to do this.

What you need is a way to call the native os functions and methods. If you can do what you need through COM or .NET, you can use one of the [`windows-only extensions`](http://php.net/manual/en/refs.utilspec.windows.php) to PHP. You will still need to figure out how to perform the lower-level windows operation, however.

Alternatively, if you just need a way to pop open a window you can go a little higher level and use a GUI toolkit. The [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org) cross-platform GUI library has been ported to PHP as [wxphp](http://wxphp.org). Perhaps you can use this.

That said, you should look into using another high-level language, such as Python.

Comment: This can be done through Phython? Heres me downloading Visual Studio :P

Comment: Almost certainly, as writing an app in Python is common. Look up the [pywin32](http://python.net/crew/mhammond/win32/) module or use IronPython in the .NET CLR (or VisualBasic, C# or F# for that matter!) However this isn't a language issue, it's a binding issue. You need to be looking at win32/COM/.NET references, not language references. Then make the appropriate calls to the windows environment using bindings in the language of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

this is not possible through PHP

Comment: So for something like this, i'd have to go through C and run it as a service? or something like that? if possible, might you have a few pointers into the right direction? Preferably the Language

Comment: it would have to be some sort of desktop application such as some sort of C based language, possibly Java...

Comment: Much appreciated; will re-search now. Thankyou